Fix macro to make it work on any workbook regardless of file name
I am trying to make this work when any workbook is opened not just on one with this filename.  Can anyone help?
Sub Exportformat()
'`your text`
' Exportformat Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+F
'
Cells.Select
Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TimeEntries_2024_09_18-2024_09_").sort.SortFields. _
    Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TimeEntries_2024_09_18-2024_09_").sort.SortFields. _
    Add2 Key:=Range("C2:C154"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TimeEntries_2024_09_18-2024_09_").sort.SortFields. _
    Add2 Key:=Range("E2:E154"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TimeEntries_2024_09_18-2024_09_").sort.SortFields. _
    Add2 Key:=Range("F2:F154"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
    DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TimeEntries_2024_09_18-2024_09_").sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:K154")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
End Sub

It will only work with a workbook with the same name.

This macro is able to work with any workbook, but it should contain the worksheet "TimeEntries_2024_09_18-2024_09_".
You can replace ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TimeEntries_2024_09_18-2024_09_") by ActiveSheet to allow the macro to work with any name sheet which is active, but consider the macro is required the predefined structure of the worksheet, and it isn't able to work with any sheet correctly.
